# Different macro stringification rules in Clang and MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, clang, c-preprocessor

I found there is a difference in macro stringification in MSVC and Clang. Is it possible to write a stringification macro in Clang that works the same as stringification in MSVC?

```
#define __IN_QUOTES(str) #str
#define IN_QUOTES(str) __IN_QUOTES(str)

#define HELLO_WORLD Hello world

int main()
{
#ifdef _MSVC_LANG
    printf("%s", "MSVC\r\n");
#else
    printf("%s", "CLANG\r\n");
#endif
    printf("%s", IN_QUOTES(HELLO_WORLD));

    return 0;
}
```

This code works same in both Clang and MSVC, but if I write line 3 as

```
#define HELLO_WORLD Hello, world
```

it will be compilable in MSVC (with "Hello, world") in output, but not compilable in Clang with an error "too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation".
The question is it possible to write IN_QUOTES macro that could produce "Hello, world" in both Clang and MSVC?
I've tried

```
#define IN_QUOTES((str)) __IN_QUOTES(str)
```

It returns "(Hello, world)" in Clang and in MSVC, but for me is interesting to obtain it without parentheses.

Comment: Would `__VA_ARGS__` help?

Comment: Well, the program with `#define HELLO_WORLD Hello, world` is ill-formed. Clang is correct to reject it, MSVC is wrong to accept it. The first step on the road of getting both to compile it would be to fix the code so that it's a valid program.

Answer (score 1):

The following is correct, and should work on any conformant C99 compiler:

```
#define __IN_QUOTES(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define IN_QUOTES(str) __IN_QUOTES(str)
```

It works with the MSVC versions I found on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/t25JfJ) (as well as with Clang and GCC).

Note that it will not accurately preserve whitespace, but there's not a lot you can do about that.

(I had to change the `#ifdef` to `#ifdef _MSC_VER`; none of the on-line compilers I tried seemed to define `_MSVC_LANG`.)